# i am unable to convert this php array to plain html

Tags: php, html

I am trying to write the following array into plain html

```
array(2) {
  ["data"]=> array(7) { 
    ["id"]=> string(10) "2286962277" 
    ["username"]=> string(14) "john john" 
    ["profile_picture"]=> string(87) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t-19025_a.jpg" 
    ["full_name"]=> string(14) "john" 
    ["bio"]=> string(4) "wish" 
    ["website"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["counts"]=> array(3) { 
      ["media"]=> int(0) 
      ["follows"]=> int(152) 
      ["followed_by"]=> int(1001)
    }
  }
  ["meta"]=> array(1) { 
    ["code"]=> int(200) 
  } 
}
```

using this code

```
<?php 
$user = $array->username;
echo $user;
?>
```

but this wont work..
i also tried

```
$user = $array['username'];
```

that still doesn't work..
What should i write?

Comment: Check My Ans... @Devanshu

Comment: That's **not** a `var_dump()` of your array `["username"]=> string(14) "john john"` ... "john john" would be `string(9)` - show us the *real* array.

Comment: @CD001 I Can not show the real array , that contains some sensitive information like passwords too!

Comment: Then replace the sensitive information with `*******`, we can't help you if we don't have the correct informations.

Comment: oki - well I've just put that data into an array (called `$array`) done a `var_dump()` and got something similar to that and I've got no problem accessing the username with `$array['data']['username']` so there's something else going on that we can't see.

Comment: @CD001 Can you show me full code , how you achieve that?

Comment: @DevanshuGoyal it's nothing nobody else has said - so I'll delete it when you update your question to show us **how** you're generating your `$array`

Comment: .... **please** tell me you're **not** doing something like `$array = print_r(array( ... ), true)` and so actually assigning the string output from `print_r` to your `$array` variable...

Comment: I am actually getting this ....

Comment: I am using json_decode($json , true);

Comment: Turn on error reporting e.g. `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and do you get a load of notices like: `<b>Notice</b>:  Use of undefined constant data - assumed 'data' in ...` ?

Comment: Here's what I think is happening - you're literally reading the `var_dump()` output as a string (like `$array = "array(2) { ..`) **and** you've got error trapping turned off. **So** when you do `echo $array['data']['username'];` you're getting undefined offsets because `$a` is a string, so that essentially becomes `$array[0]` which is the first letter of the string or `a` as you found. Now when you did `$array[2]['username']` you got `r` - which is the 2nd `r` in the word `array` from your `var_dump` - so your array is **not** an array, it's the string output from `var_dump()` somehow.

Comment: Rolled it back to *revision 2* as that makes most sense for the output parsing that's come up on the comments.

Answer (score 2):

**Example::**  `var_dump($myarray)`

```
array(2) {
  ["data"]=> array(7) { 
    ["id"]=> string(10) "2286962277" 
    ["username"]=> string(14) "john john" 
    ["profile_picture"]=> string(87) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t-19025_a.jpg" 
    ["full_name"]=> string(14) "john" 
    ["bio"]=> string(4) "wish" 
    ["website"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["counts"]=> array(3) { 
      ["media"]=> int(0) 
      ["follows"]=> int(152) 
      ["followed_by"]=> int(1001)
    }
  }
  ["meta"]=> array(1) { 
    ["code"]=> int(200) 
  } 
}
```

> Now If Want To Get Data From Array Try This..

```
echo $myarray['data']['id'];  // For ID
echo $myarray['data']['username'];  // For Username
```

Comment: it is showing alphabet at position "2" which is "r" in "array"

Comment: The shown output is `var_dump` not `print_r` - `array(2) {` means it's an array with 2 elements (`data` and `meta`) **not** that the index is 2.

Comment: i recieve information in json format too,can i use that to convert into plain text

Comment: if you have data in json then you can direct decode it ... easily

Comment: If it's a `json` then it's a *string* not an *array* ... until you `json_decode()` it.

Comment: If this isn't working there's something else going on basically, since this is correct for the question asked.

Comment: I'm now 99% certain that the array **isn't** an array - but the string output from `var_dump` - it explains why every string index, e.g. `$array['data']['username'];` has come up **a** (first letter in `array(2) { ...`) since `data` and `username` are undefined indexes on a string, essentially resulting in `$array[0]` - the first letter of the string. It also explains why when you suggested `$array[2]['username']` it came up **r** (2nd "r" in "array" - the 3rd letter in the string).

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to access the username is the following:

```
$array['data']['username']
```

If you use [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) (prefixed by `<pre>`, if you're rendering it in HTML), you'll be able to see the structure more clearly.

Comment: what happens when you echo `$array['data']['full_name']`? `$array['data']['bio']`?

Answer (score 0):

`$array->username` would try to get the property `username` from the **object** `$array`.
However, you have a simple multidimesional array, so to access `username` you have to use the normal array syntax:

```
$array['data']['username']
```